# Configure bridge/router to work same as Windows 10 mobile hotspot?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge

Is there any way to configure a router in the same way as how the Mobile Hotspot functionality in Windows 10 works (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027762/windows-use-your-pc-as-a-mobile-hotspot)?

I want to create a home network with own SSID by sharing another WiFi with WPA2 enterprise security. Simple bridging is not officially supported, but internet connection sharing via the Win10 Mobile Hotspot functionality is working and allowed (recommended solution by network admin to connect devices that do not support WPA2 enterprise)

As I do not want to have my laptop on at all times to use the WiFi, I am looking for a more convenient solution. Is there any way I can configure my CPE210 (or any other router - I have two other older ones at home, they do not support client mode though) in the same way as Win10 works?

When I just use the normal Client Mode of the CPE210, I cannot achieve internet connectivity. Connecting to the network seems fine though, as I am able to input everything relevant to log into the network, and it shows me that it is connected to the network with TX and RX rates of up to 54Mbps. I assume I cannot get internet on my end device due to bridging not being officially supported, or could it be other reasons here? When trying the same procedure with a Cellular Hotspot that I create on my smartphone, I can get proper internet connectivity through Client Mode with the CPE.

PS: Same result with Bridge mode - can connect to the AP, and the Client can connect to the WiFI, but no internet connectivity.

PPS: Looking into ipconfig, I am always assigned a 169.254. IP. That does not happen if I try the same procedure with a different network that I want to bridge/share, then I am assigned a normal IP.

Comment: You have to configure your router in repeater or bridge mode.

Comment: I did try bridge mode - same result as in Client mode, no internet connectivity. Similarly, in the GUI, it shows that it is connected as a client to the WiFI, and the bridge AP is also set up properly so that I can connect my end device. However, my laptop always shows Limited connectivity, probably because I am not assigned a correct IP (169.254.xxxx)


Repeater mode is not allowed for the network.

Comment: Ok, CPE210 is just a WiFi Access Point. It usualy used in point-to-point connection for long range WiFi. It may work as AP (standard WiFi Access point, Internet connected by cable). Also it can work as Client (in this case it connects to other AP and downlink received data to cable, you need second WiFi AP, router or something to provide WiFi connection which is connected to CPE by cable). It also may work as Repeater. In this case it simple expands WiFi range. Bridge mode is more or less similar to client except it does some basic routing. And in bridge you also need other WiFi AP.

Comment: I am aware of that, most of my tests I have done in client mode where my laptop was connected to the CPE via LAN. Also, in bridge mode, the CPE is able to set-up the additional WiFi AP.

However, this still does not solve the issue of no internet connectivity / not getting an IP address. Can anyone tell me how the network should be configured, i.e. what to put for CPE210 IP, Netmask, IP Gateway, Primary DNS, etc.? I did assign the ones I would otherwise get if connected directly with my laptop, and also put a static IP for the router in the range of the network

Comment: CPE210 can not act as router (what you need is router to route all local traffict to your IPS WiFi network). Bridge mode simple bridges between different networks but it does not route traffic. As I wrote you need any WiFi router to get what you need.

Comment: Again, this is not where my problem lies. I am currently not getting internet connectivity while being connected to the CPE210 via ethernet (I am not even using the Bridge mode, which is being described by the manual as AP-Client-ROUTER though). 

I am looking for support in properly setting up the CPE210 to get internet connectivity at all, so also via ethernet - let's assume that only client mode exists. I can worry about the router part later

Comment: In Client router mode you CPE must get IP settings from your ISP. Then it must have other IP settings for local network. Your devices that is connected to CPE via cable must be in the same net as local settings in your CPE. For example, your ISP assigned this IP settings for your CPE when it connected to its WiFi network: IP: 192.170.1.2, mask 255.255.0.0, DNS 192.150.1,1. Your local network settings for CPE must be IP: 192.168.1.1,  mask: 255.255.255.0, gatewa: 192.170.1.2, DNS: 192.150.1.1.

Comment: Next all your devices must have IP settings like: IP: 192.168.1.2-255; mask: 255.255.255.0, DNS: 192.168.1.1, GateWay: 192.168.1.1

Comment: I forgot to say that you also have to enable NAT on your CPE (if it runs in router mode it must have NAT)